# E-mail submission form: user automatically gets email with document after checking specific checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, forms, pdf, attachment

I am looking for a script (php, jQuery ?) for an email form,
where a user can choose from different documents (pdfs) via a checkbox.

The user fills out name and email, and after submitting the form automatically gets an email back, with a greeting (hello mr. x, thanks for ordering our pdf...).

The chosen document is attached.
I couldn't find any jQuery solution. do I need php?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: jQuery cannot send mails. PHP can. You may use AJAX to call the PHP mailer with the correct options. Sounds pretty straight forward. Read the manuals and try again.

Answer (score 0):

@Truth is basically right, but let me explain a bit more.

jQuery runs in the browser, ie on your user's machine. You can modify data that's on the website, but not on another machine (so since your PDF isn't on the user's computer to begin with, jQuery's no good).

PHP on the other hand is an example of server-side technology; it runs on the server (ie where your data is, and where your documents lie) and constructs HTML pages based on your programming.

AJAX is a way of letting the two interact without a page reload, but it's not really necessary. What you want is a HTML form that gets sent to a PHP script and a PHP script that receives this call and reacts accordingly.